# Confidence Intervals for Unknown Mean and Unknown Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval, sampling

Given a random variable $X$ which follows a normal distribution with unknown mean and unknown variance: $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Say we have $n$ observations of samples from $X$: $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$. Given a new random sample $x_{n+1}$ generated from $X$ and a real number $b$, how to compute the probability $p(x_{n+1} \le b)$ with confidence interval $1-\alpha$ ($0 \le \alpha <1$)?

Comment: This looks related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#Unknown_mean,_unknown_variance.

Comment: $1-\alpha$ is not an interval. Did you mean "with confidence *level* $1-\alpha$"? Are you looking for a confidence interval for $p(x_{n+1} \le b)$ with confidence level $1-\alpha$?